# Java Graphics - Drawing Lines

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, line, coordinates

I am having some problems drawing lines in my Java program.

I wish to play with some Maze Generation Algorithms but am currently struggling to set up a board to visualize the process and creation of the mazes. Below is my current Setup:

I generate a grid (2D Array) 50 x 25, each block is 20 pixels wide and 20 pixels tall, now for each grid I want to draw each of the four walls as lines.

I get the starting x and y coordinate of each block by multiplying the for loop values (used to traverse the array) by the block size. For Example if I am currently looking at grid[2][3] then the pixel coordinates will be (40, 60). My problem is that the South wall and the East Wall are not being drawn, nothing is showing in my program even though the coordinates are being generated, my North Wall and West Wall are however being drawn.

I am trying to get the walls Coordinates by adjusting the positions as follows, if I want to draw the south wall and the starting x and y coordinates of the block are (40, 60). Then the 2 points that should be used to draw the South Wall should be, (40, 80) and (60, 80).

Below is the Render Method that I am currently using:

```
private void renderBoard(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {

            Node node = grid[i][j];

            // Draw the Node's Background
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);

            // Draw the Node's North Wall
            if (node.walls.contains(Walls.NORTH)) {

                Line line = new Line(i, j, Walls.NORTH, blockSize);

                // System.out.println("Point1 (X1: " + line.x1 + "  Y1: " + line.y1 + ") Point2 (X2: " + line.x2 + "  Y2: " + line.y2 + ")");

                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);

            }

            // Draw the Node's South Wall
            if (node.walls.contains(Walls.SOUTH)) {

                Line line = new Line(i, j, Walls.SOUTH, blockSize);

                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again the North wall is drawn while nothing is drawn for the South Wall. I initially thought it might be because I was passing in the two for loop variables in the wrong order. But that didn't seem to change anything

This is my Line Class:

```
class Line {

    // Current X Y Coordinates in the Grid
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // The Lines Start and End Coordinates
    public int x1, x2;
    public int y1, y2;

    public Line(int x, int y, Walls wall, int blocksize) {

        // Here we get the pixel coordinate based off of the current Array Position
        this.x = (x * blocksize);
        this.y = (y * blocksize);

        switch(wall) {

            case NORTH:

                x1 = this.x;
                y1 = this.y;
                x2 = this.x + blocksize;
                y2 = this.y;

                break;

            case SOUTH:

                x1 = this.x;
                y1 = this.y + blocksize;
                x2 = this.x + blocksize;
                y2 = this.y + blocksize;

                break;

            case EAST:

                x1 = this.x + blocksize;
                y1 = this.y;
                x2 = this.x + blocksize;
                y2 = this.y + blocksize;

                break;

            case WEST:

                x1 = this.x;
                y1 = this.y;
                x2 = this.x;
                y2 = this.y + blocksize;

                break;

        }
    }
}
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that I am doing something really really silly or missing something very small, any help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: In `renderBoard(Graphics g)`, what are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Those are the dimensions of the array, x = 50, y = 25.

Comment: When constructing the Line: `new Line(i, j, Walls.NORTH, blockSize);` Should you be passing in `i` and `j` as parameters, or `i*blocksize` and `j*blocksize`?

Comment: On a side note, in your `Line` constructor, a `switch`-`case` statement will look much neater compared to `else-if`(s). `Enums` are compatible with `switch` statements.

Comment: @copeg I handle the multiplication inside the Line Class Constructor, @ Bruce Wayne I shall switch it to a Switch - Case statement, I agree with you that it would look much neater